# Finding the angle of in a triangle

Tags: geometry

> The side $AC$ of $\triangle ABC$ is a diameter of a circle. Side $BC$ intersects with this circle at point $M$ and side $BA$ intersects this circle at point $K$. If $S_{\triangle ABC}=9S_{\triangle BKM}$, find $\angle ABC$.

I can prove that $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle BKM$ and $3BM=AB$ and $3BK=BC$, but I have no idea about $\angle ABC$.

Comment: What is S here ?

Comment: @rsadhvika areaaa

Comment: This is a translated question ;) In this particular non-universally accepted mathematical language, S refers to area. @aid78

Comment: Can you tell how you get $3BM = AB$, because after that its pretty easy

Comment: This looks like a high school Euclidean geometry question.

Comment: @KingTut $BK \cdot AB= BM \cdot BC$ then from $9\cdot 0.5\cdot BK\cdot BM \sin B=0.5\cdot AB\cdot BC \sin B $

Comment: @aid is it power of a point?

Comment: $BK⋅AB=BM⋅BC$  and $9⋅BK⋅BM=AB⋅BC$ gives $9⋅BK^2=BC^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $∠AMC = \dfrac{π}{2}$, then$$
\frac{1}{3} AB = BM = AB \cos B \Longrightarrow ∠B = \arccos \frac{1}{3}.
$$